# Support vector regression and paremeters

Tags: python, svm, forecast

I am doing load forecasting using SVR(kernel='rbf').How can I understand which is the best value for parameters C, epsilon and gamma?Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that you are using scikit-learn. In this case use [Grid Search Cross Validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)  or [Randomized Search Cross Validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV) to find the best parameters.

```
sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, scoring=None, cv=None, ...)
```

In these approaches you basically loop over possible sets of your parameters, specified via `param_grid`. For each set you perform a cross-validation (default is 3-fold, but you can specify it via `cv` parameter). Cross-validation gives you the mean value and deviation of your 'scoring' parameter (e.g. 'accuracy' for classification, 'r2' for regression). The set of parameters with the best 'scoring' is the winner.

See example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/randomized_search.html#example-model-selection-randomized-search-py). It also show how to output not only *the* best set of parameters, but also "top-N". I find it very useful in building intuition about my model.